# Trying to Delete the data displayed in my tables

Tags: php, mysql, button, delete-row

I have been able to display the data from my database on to my website and I'm trying to delete a single row.

Now the button works but it completely deletes everything as you may tell from the code.

I have no idea on how to assign the delete button to a specific row in my table, where it just deletes that data in that specific row.

On top of this I have one delete button that sits upon my table and have no clue on how to set separate delete buttons for each row given.

admin.php (Displaying my data)

```
<?php

echo "<table style='box'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Role</th>
<th>Email</th><th>Username</th><th>Delete</th><th>Amend</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {

  function __construct($it) {
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
  }

  function current() {
    return "<td style='box'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
  }
  function beginChildren(){
    echo "<tr>";
  }

  function endChildren(){
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}

require 'connection.php';

try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username FROM users");
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v){
    echo $v;
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e){
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>

<form method="post" action="delete.php">
  <input <input class="btn-default" type="submit" name="login" value="Delete">
</form>

<?php
echo "</table>";

?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$database = 'tutor_database';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //sql to delete record.
  $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = id";

  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "Record deleted!";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

I would show an image but I don't have enough reputation points to display  it.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause in your `DELETE` statement will always return to true. On every row, ID will always equal ID. Hence, everything is deleted. You need to pass a parameter to delete script to filter on the row you want deleted. You can do so by a hidden HTML input value using `get="method"` of `<form>`.

However, the key is how to obtain that id from webpage's select query. Additionally, you will want to put the input button at the end  of each row to delete the corresponding row's id. For these two items, you might have to return to traditional loop onto web page instead of the `RecursiveArrayIterator()` because we need to add a non fetched object (form delete button) into table.

**admin.php**  *(notice form button as last table cell of each row)*

```
...same code as above...

try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Role, Email, Username FROM users");
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  while($row = $result->fetch()) {  
  ?>
    <tr>    
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td> 
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td> 
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['Role']; ?></td> 
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td> 
     <td style="box"> <?php echo $row['Username']; ?></td> 
     <td>
       <form method="get" action="delete.php">
           <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
           <input class="btn-default" type="submit" name="login" value="Delete">
       </form>
     </td>
   <tr>
  <?php
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e){
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

**delete.php**  *(notice $id generated from $GET() and used in delete query)*

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$database = 'tutor_database';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // OBTAIN ROWID FROM $_GET
  if(isset($_GET['rowid'])) {
        $id = $_GET['rowid'];
  }

  // DELETE SPECIFIED ROW
  $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$id;

  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "Record deleted!";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tried your method for the admin.php file but for some reason the records are not showing any longer like before. I may be missing something here? Not sure. I am able to see the header of my tables but the data from the database does not show like it used to.

Comment: Are there records in the users table? Recall, on previous attempts, you deleted everything.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your `DELETE` statement does not include a variable.

```
//sql to delete record.
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = id";
```

You need something more like:

```
//sql to delete record.
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = " . $id;
```

where $id is defined with the ID of the selected row.

Let's address another "hidden" problem.

> Now the button works but it completely deletes everything as you may tell from the code.

Given the fact that you said this deletes ALL the records, I would guess that the `id` of each of your rows is the string `'id'` and not a unique integer value.

`DELETE FROM {table} WHERE id = {number}` does not delete ALL records.  It only deletes records matching the condition. You should make sure that you are setting `id`'s correctly when adding rows. The `id` column should have the following properties: `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Well I don't know how to put it. But it definitely deleted everything associated with the unique integer value once I checked the database values over again after pressing the button.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the data from the database before and after `delete.php` is called?

Comment: I would use pictures to show yout the before and after results but unfortunately the website wont allow me. From what I can tell you before the deletion (now) there are two id's set at 18 and 19 with the first name, last name, role and etc with the relevent information. Once I pressed the delete button it gave me the return message of `"Record Deleted!"` and then checking the database I see `Empty set (0.00 sec)`. And that's with the `id = id;`

Comment: I am going to guess that this `id = id;` is a bug that reduces to `DELETE from users;` which is a command that deletes all rows from the entire table.  Try hardcoding the `id` value to something like: `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 20;` after you enter another few rows in.

Comment: I have tried your method and it does work where the only the specified ID will be deleted from the database.

Comment: So we have found the problem.  You are now in a good place of understanding and should be able to correct it.  Good luck and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow what you have. Have you tried setting the id to a var before doing?

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = id";
```

Example:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: I didn't use any variable in the beginning it was just as you saw it in my code.